# Is there a way to simplify $a\sqrt{1-a^2} + \arcsin(a) = \pi/4$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, transcendental-equations

A while ago, I was eating pizza and wondered that if you were to cut parallel to one of the radii, how far along would you need to cut in order to split a slice's area in half?

In attempting to find a general answer for a sector with radius $r$ and angle $\theta$, I used some trigonometry to find
$$a\sin\theta\sqrt{r^2 - a^2 \sin^2\theta} + r^2 \arcsin\left(\frac{a\sin\theta}{r}\right) - a^2\sin\theta\cos\theta = \frac{1}{2}r^2\theta$$
where $a$ is the distance along  from the origin where we start our cut. After seeing this I had absolutely no idea how or even if I could continue, so I tried $r=1$ and $\theta = \pi/2$, i.e. a quarter-circle with radius 1. This gives:
$$a\sqrt{1-a^2} + \arcsin(a) = \pi/4$$
Is there any way this expression can be further simplified?

Comment: Similar to [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html). You could put it into polar coordinates

Comment: Could you check your first equation, please ? If you make $r=1$ and $\theta=\frac \pi 2$, the last equation would be $$a\sqrt{1-a^2} + \arcsin(a) = \frac \pi 2$$ Try to fix it since the problem is interesting. Cheers :-)

Comment: Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many $x$ and $\sin(x)$ transcendental equations on this site, but why not add another answer to one of them using the [incomplete beta function $\text B_x(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=beta%28x%2Ca%2Cb%29):

$$x=a\sqrt{1-a^2}+\sin^{-1}(a)=\int_0^{a^2}\frac{\sqrt{1-t}}{\sqrt t}dt=\text B_{a^2}\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$$

Therefore, we use [inverse beta regularized $\text I^{-1}_s(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=inversebetaregularized)

$$a=\pm\sqrt{\text I^{-1}_\frac{2x}\pi\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)}$$

[**Shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=N%5Beulergamma-%28a+sqrt%281-a%5E2%29%2Basin%28a%29%29%2C10%5D%2Ca%3Dsqrt%28inversebetaregularized%282eulergamma%2Fpi%2C1%2F2%2C3%2F2%29%29). With $a=\frac\pi2,\frac\pi4$ etc, you transform the circle problem into a quartile or median of a [**T distribution CDF**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=t+distribution+cdf), in terms of [beta regularized $\text I_x(a,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=BetaRegularized), with $3$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: I seem to have created a problem way beyond my own understanding...Time to do some reading!

Comment: @Napthus. Do you see what your pizza caused ? Anyway, very interesting problem. Thanks for it since I had a lot of fun. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you want to solve for $a$ the equation
$$a\sqrt{1-a^2} + \arcsin(a) =k$$ expand the lhs as a series to obtain
$$k=2a-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\beta_n|}{\gamma_n}\, a^{2n+1}$$ where the  coefficients$\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ form respectively the sequences $A091154$ and $A143582$ in $OEIS$.

Using [seriesreversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html), the approximation
$$a=\frac{1}{2}k+\frac{1}{48}k^3+\frac{13 }{3840}k^5+\frac{493
   }{645120}k^7+\frac{37369}{185794560} k^9+O\left(k^{11}\right)$$

Tryin for a few values of $k \lt \frac \pi 2$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate}&\text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.050021 &  0.050021 \\
 0.2 & 0.100168 &  0.100168 \\
 0.3 & 0.150571 &  0.150571 \\
 0.4 & 0.201369 &  0.201369 \\
 0.5 & 0.252716 &  0.252716 \\
 0.6 & 0.304787 &  0.304787 \\
 0.7 & 0.357786 &  0.357787 \\
 0.8 & 0.411963 &  0.411969 \\
 0.9 & 0.467630 &  0.467654 \\
 1.0 & 0.525184 &  0.525268 \\
 1.1 & 0.585145 &  0.585410 \\
 1.2 & 0.648200 &  0.648986 \\
 1.3 & 0.715269 &  0.717509 \\
 1.4 & 0.787586 &  0.793961 \\
 1.5 & 0.866810 &  0.886571 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Also $$
a = \sin \left( {k + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{J_n (n)}}{n}\sin (2nk)} } \right)
$$ with $J_n$ being the Bessel function of the first kind.

Comment: @Gary. This is beautiful !

Comment: @Gary How does one begin to show this identity?

Comment: @DinosaurEgg It follows directly from the Kapteyn series solution of Kepler's equation.

Answer (score 0):

*I prefer to put a second answer for the first equation.*

Let $a=x\,r$ and simplify. You then need to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\theta ^2-2 x \sin (\theta ) \sqrt{1-x^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}+x^2 \sin (2\theta )-2 \sin ^{-1}(x \sin (\theta ))$$ Hoping that $x$ is not too large, te Taylor expansion is
$$f(x)=\theta ^2-4 x \sin (\theta )+x^2 \sin (2 \theta )+\frac{2}{3} x^3 \sin^3(\theta )+\frac{1}{10} x^5 \sin ^5(\theta )+O\left(x^7\right)$$
Using series reversion, an *estimate* is
$$\color{red}{x=\frac{\theta ^2 \csc (\theta )}{2949120}\,\, \sum_{n=0}^5c_n\,\theta^{2n}}$$ where
$$\color{blue}{\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & c_n \\
 0 & 737280 \\
 1 & 92160 \cot (\theta ) \\
 2 & 23040 \cot ^2(\theta )+7680 \\
 3 & 7200 \cot (\theta ) \csc ^2(\theta )-2400 \cot (\theta ) \\
 4 & 2520 \cot ^2(\theta ) \csc ^2(\theta )+312 \\
 5 & 28 \cot (\theta )+945 \cot (\theta ) \csc ^4(\theta )-630 \cot (\theta
   ) \csc ^2(\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)}$$
and then some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\theta & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.025362 &  0.025362 \\
 0.2 & 0.051643 &  0.051643 \\
 0.3 & 0.079136 &  0.079136 \\
 0.4 & 0.108134 &  0.108134 \\
 0.5 & 0.138936 &  0.138937 \\
 0.6 & 0.171846 &  0.171850 \\
 0.7 & 0.207172 &  0.207186 \\
 0.8 & 0.245233 &  0.245268 \\
 0.9 & 0.286352 &  0.286434 \\
 1.0 & 0.330859 &  0.331035 \\
 1.1 & 0.379088 &  0.379442 \\
 1.2 & 0.431377 &  0.432048 \\
 1.3 & 0.488066 &  0.489281 \\
 1.4 & 0.549468 &  0.551612 \\
 1.5 & 0.615792 &  0.619572 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

And we could do much better, be sure ! It is just the problem of expanding $f(x)$ to higher orders.

For example, expanding $f(x)$ up to $O(x^{15})$, the results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\theta & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.025362 &  0.025362 \\
 0.2 & 0.051643 &  0.051643 \\
 0.3 & 0.079136 &  0.079136 \\
 0.4 & 0.108134 &  0.108134 \\
 0.5 & 0.138937 &  0.138937 \\
 0.6 & 0.171850 &  0.171850 \\
 0.7 & 0.207186 &  0.207186 \\
 0.8 & 0.245268 &  0.245268 \\
 0.9 & 0.286434 &  0.286434 \\
 1.0 & 0.331035 &  0.331035 \\
 1.1 & 0.379441 &  0.379442 \\
 1.2 & 0.432044 &  0.432048 \\
 1.3 & 0.489269 &  0.489281 \\
 1.4 & 0.551572 &  0.551612 \\
 1.5 & 0.619454 &  0.619572 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Looking at the very first term of the series expansion, we have a first estimate
$$x_0=\frac{1}{4} \theta ^2 \csc (\theta )$$ Use the first iteration of Halley method and obtain
$$x_{1} = x_0 - \frac {2 \,f(x_0)\, f'(x_0)} {2 \,{[f'(x_0)]}^2 - f(x_0)\, f''(x_0)}$$ where
$$f'(x)=-4 \sin (\theta ) \left(\sqrt{1-x^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}-x \cos (\theta)\right)$$
$$f''(x)=4 \sin (\theta ) \left(\cos (\theta )+\frac{x \sin ^2(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-x^2 \sin ^2(\theta )}}\right)$$ The formula is a bit too long to type here but $x_1$ is totally explicit.

We know that $x_1$ is an underestimate of the root and, since $$f(x_1)\times f''(x_1)~> ~0$$ by Darboux theorem, the exact solution will be reached without any overshoot.

This is simpler to use and quite good. Repeating the table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\theta & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.1 & 0.025362 &  0.025362 \\
 0.2 & 0.051643 &  0.051643 \\
 0.3 & 0.079136 &  0.079136 \\
 0.4 & 0.108134 &  0.108134 \\
 0.5 & 0.138937 &  0.138937 \\
 0.6 & 0.171849 &  0.171850 \\
 0.7 & 0.207184 &  0.207186 \\
 0.8 & 0.245265 &  0.245268 \\
 0.9 & 0.286426 &  0.286434 \\
 1.0 & 0.331020 &  0.331035 \\
 1.1 & 0.379415 &  0.379442 \\
 1.2 & 0.432005 &  0.432048 \\
 1.3 & 0.489217 &  0.489281 \\
 1.4 & 0.551523 &  0.551612 \\
 1.5 & 0.619462 &  0.619572 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: If I plug $\theta = \pi/4$ into https://math24.pro/transcendental_equation I get $x = 0.3178...$. Am I missing something? Thanks :)

Comment: I shall check tomorrow morning. Dinner Time here. Cheers.  @Napthus

Comment: @Napthus   https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?key=&i=FindRoot%5BPi%5E2%2F16+%2B+x%5E2+-+Sqrt%5B2%5D*x*Sqrt%5B1+-+x%5E2%2F2%5D+-+2*ArcSin%5Bx%2FSqrt%5B2%5D%5D%3D%3D0%2C%7Bx%2C1%2F4%7D%5D confirms my result.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindRoot%5BPi%5E2%2F16+%2B+x%5E2+-+Sqrt%5B2%5D%5D), with the right bracket, just says “try the following”.

Answer (score -1):

If you let $x= \arcsin a$ then $a=\sin x$ and your equation is
$$\sin x \cos x + x = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

or $$\sin 2x + 2x = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

That seems like a transcendental equation that might have been studied.

Comment: It seems to me that the first equation is not correct. Any idea to fix it . Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  If you have a problem, say what it is.  It's not cute when adults try to be mysterious.

Comment: I am sorry ! I was suupose to send the comment to the poster, not to you. Cheers :-)